How to fix Android Studio Koala intermittenty losing devices?
After upgrading Android Studio from Jellyfish to Koala on Windows, the IDE intermittently loses connection to attached devices. This makes it impossible to use the debugger. Is there a way to fix this other than reverting to Jellyfish?
Steps to reproduce:
1. Connect phone via USB
2. Launch project in Android Studio
3. See the device show up in the upper right
of the Android Studio window (image attached)
4. Launch app with "Run->Debug App"
5. Waiting for debugger to attach, notice the device name no longer appears and
instead the IDE says "No devices" where the device name used to be
6. Notice error in lower left of IDE: "Debugger process finished with exit code 1"
7. Notice app runs as expected on the device
Hopefully this is a known problem they're working on?

It's possible that updates to adb make it more sensitive to flaky cables. For example, they're starting to do USB speed testing, to let you know if you could have faster results with a faster cable. So... have you tried swapping cables?

I have the same issue and have yet to find a solution for it. Happens on any device with different cables

I've tried different cables and devices and ports. Didn't help.

I just installed Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 1 and it may have fixed the issue. Hopefully others can confirm this.

Try using the jellyfish version of Android Studio instead of the Koala version, which causes errors and wastes development time. I was able to connect my device and use Jellyfish instead of Koala.

You can get the earlier version of Android Studio by clicking this link.

Android Studio Archives
and try again

Thanks, but my question was if there's a known fix for this other than reverting to Jellyfish.

I solved this updating platform-tools to latest version (In my case, latest is 35.0.2 jul/2024).
https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools
Replace in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
